# Replacement for delayed_paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, resque

I use resque to process my background jobs and paperclip for uploaded files. So, i had to use delayed_paperclip to make those 2 libraries work together. But this gem has some bugs, and is not maintained anymore.

So my question is, what do you guys use to handle asynchronously uploads on your webapps?

Comment: Can you try out version 2.4.5.2 on rubygems? I'm the new maintainer, delayed_paperclip should be up-and-running now. If the bug you're running into isn't fixed, file an issue please! - https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/issues/new

Comment: Wondering if we can get this closed? https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/ is still being updated.